# How to send name of someone in Discord with bot in Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, mention

I was coding my Python Discord bot which, on asking,

```
Warn <@anyone>
```

Shall send DM to the `@anyone` in Discord.

Till now, i have written,

```
if message.content.startswith('Warn '):
```

now I want to convert the whole message to String format and then remove the 'Warn ' from it. Thus I will get the name of `@anyone` easily. But I am not able to do that. Further, I don't know whether the conversion to String is possible or not.

Is anyone able to answer my query? Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: you shouldn't really be using on_message for commands, consider using the [commands extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html). It would allow you to make this command in like 3 lines

Answer (score 0):

to get a use by doing @user this is how I do it

```
@client.command() #to start the command
async def warn(ctx, member : discord.member): #name and import ctx / other things too 
       await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}")
```

if i did it wrong please tell me its been a bit

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "name and import ctx", there's nothing to import - ctx is just an argument. If you're not typehinting it as `commands.Context`, which you aren't doing in your example, then there's nothing to import.